# How to convert Struts1.0 tag ResponseUtils method write to Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tags, struts-1

I am working on converting a Struts 1 site to Struts 2, not easy task as everything have changed from one framework to the next.

I was hoping someone has used or know about the `org.apache.struts.util.ResponseUtils` specifically the write method.
We are using Struts 1.0 and we are currently using this line in the code:

```
 ResponseUtils.write(pageContext, results.toString());
```

Has anyone seen this tag? use this tag? and then convert it to Struts 2?

I have searched online and found some good tutorials and I am also reading "Struts2 in Action" which I saw recommended here in other post. But, very few sites or posts talk about specific tags.

I will appreciate any advice or hint that can let me to the path of success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own `ResponseUtils` with the method

```
public void write(PageContext pageContext, String text)
        throws JspException {

    JspWriter writer = pageContext.getOut();

    try {
        writer.print(text);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new JspException(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: I saw this implementation in the newer version of Struts 1 but I was checking to see if someone had seen it implemented in Struts 2. However, I had not tried until you recommended it above. I did create a new class using most of the method and it is working good. Thanks.

Comment: Struts2 has dropped support for custom tags, and moved to the component tag's UI support. Read more about struts tags http://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-tags.html